# Get twitter @user matching a csv list of names

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I have a CSV file with a column that contains full names.

| FullName | Twitter User |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe |  |
| Jane Doe |  |

I want to fill the column "Twitter User" with the corresponding Twitter usernames.
The desired output should look like this :

| FullName | Twitter User |
| --- | --- |
| John Doe | @JohnDoe |
| Jane Doe | @JaneDoe |

Is there a way to do that using python and Twitter API ?

Comment: How does the program know the Twitter user name corresponding to a real name, if it exists at all?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The goal is to find the username based on a given name. The code should try to find if the name exists in Twitter and then find the associated username.

Comment: What exactly was the problem when you tried to do that? Did you read the documentation of the Twitter API to see what it can do?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I found the inverse of what I want to exactly do : https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/api-reference/get-users-by-username-list